# map function is not iterating the state objects(in array format) in react.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, dictionary, state

I'm building an iTunes search project in react.js in which it fetch the music album data of the name entered in the input field. I'm using iTunes search api to get the data the data is in json format which contains 50 objects for each search.

The data which i get from the api is stored/set to the data state(i'm using hook to store the data object) in an array format.

Here i'm getting an data of each object by `setData([json.results[0]])`

but the problem is that map function is not able to iterate over the data state array.

I have tried all the things but the map function is not iterating over the data state object.
And also it also not giving any error.

Can someone tell me why it is not working?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code.

```
import { useState } from "react"
const Search = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const handleInput = event => {
        setName(event.target.value);
    };

    const getIdata = async () => {

        let url = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + name;
        let cors = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        
        setData([]);

        fetch(url)
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(json => {
                setData([json.results])
            })

        console.log(data);
   }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h1>iTunes App</h1>
                <div>
                    <p>Search: <input className="input-field col s6" id="daal" onChange={handleInput} /></p>
                    <button onClick={getIdata} id="btn">submit</button>
                </div>
                <div className="row" id="output"></div>
            </div>



            {

                data.map(curr => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <h1>{curr.artistName}</h1>
                            {<div className="row" id="output">
                                <div className="col s4 m4 l4">
                                    <div className="card">
                                        <div className="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                                            <img className="activator" src={curr.artworkUrl100} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="card-content">
                                            <span className="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">{curr.artistName}<i
                                                className="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                                            <p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="card-reveal">
                                            <span className="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">{curr.trackCensoredName}<i
                                                className="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                                            <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>}
                        </>
                    );
                })
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Search
```

Comment: Don't do `setData([])` then another `setData([json.results])` inside `then`. Also, what do you see when you `console.log(data)` inside your `render` method before and after you send the request?

Comment: Ya i remove the `setData([])` from the code. And when i `console.log(data)` before the request i got nothing and after the request i got the object.

Comment: What kind of object? In order to use `map`, it needs to be an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are placing an array in an array with `setData([json.results])`, and `data` is set to:

```
[[ { «song» }, { «song» }, { «song» } ]]
```

Notice the double `[[` and `]]`. Set the fetched song list directly instead of wrapping it inside another array. eg. `setData(json.results)` which should result in `data` being:

```
[ { «song» }, { «song» }, { «song» } ]
```

---

The reason there is currently no error is because you only access object attributes like `curr.artistName` which works perfectly fine if `curr` is an array.

```
const curr = [];
curr.artistName //=> undefined (no error)
```

You will receive an error if you try to do anything with the resulting value and don't expect it to be `undefined`. For example `curr.artistName.split("")` will throw an error, because you cannot call `split` upon `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution and amazing explanation it worked!